# Using Chromedriver in Selenium

Tags: selenium, go

I tried installing neccessary deps with homebrew.

```
brew install selenium-server-standalone
brew install geckodriver
brew install chromedriver
```

But I can't get the selenium server to start.  It hangs at the first panic.
`panic: server did not respond on port 8080`

```
import (
"fmt"
"github.com/tebeka/selenium"
"github.com/tebeka/selenium/chrome"
"os"
"strings"
"time"
)

func StartSession() {
    // Start a Selenium WebDriver server instance (if one is not already running).
    const (
        // These paths will be different on your system.
        seleniumPath    = "/usr/local/Cellar/selenium-server-standalone/3.141.59_2/bin"
        //geckoDriverPath = "/usr/local/Cellar/geckodriver/0.29.0"
        chromeDriverPath = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
        port            = 8080
    )
    opts := []selenium.ServiceOption{
        //selenium.StartFrameBuffer(),           // Start an X frame buffer for the browser to run in.
        selenium.ChromeDriver(chromeDriverPath),
        //selenium.GeckoDriver(geckoDriverPath), // Specify the path to GeckoDriver in order to use Firefox.
        selenium.Output(os.Stderr),            // Output debug information to STDERR.
    }
    selenium.SetDebug(true)
    service, err := selenium.NewSeleniumService(seleniumPath, port, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // panic is used only as an example and is not otherwise recommended.
    }
    defer service.Stop()


    // Connect to the WebDriver instance running locally.
    //caps := selenium.Capabilities{"browserName": "firefox"}
    caps := selenium.Capabilities{"browserName": "chrome"}

    chromeCaps := chrome.Capabilities{
        Path:  "",
        Args: []string{
            "--headless", // <<<
            "--no-sandbox",
            "--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0.2 Safari/604.4.7",
        },
    }
    caps.AddChrome(chromeCaps)
    wd, err := selenium.NewRemote(caps, fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:%d/wd/hub", port))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer wd.Quit()
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you selenium path is correct? Why are you stopping the service after starting? The panic error is in the first or second "panic"?

Comment: Yes the path is correct. At the first panic.

Comment: If you start the server manually, it works?

Comment: Try setting your selenium path to point to the .jar file not only to the bin directory

Answer (score 0):

```
seleniumPath    = "/usr/local/Cellar/selenium-server-standalone/3.141.59_2/libexec/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar"
```

Setting to the path of the jar file works.